# Passing logging configuration for fatjar(in vertx)

Tags: java, logging, groovy, vert.x

I want to change levels of logging as part of a configuration file . Well I can place logging configuration as part of src/main/resources but that defeats the purpose as jar has to be exploded for that.

What I want to do is put a configuration file as part of vertx deployment.

I tried passing a -cp logging.properties but that didn't work.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `-cp` switch for what command? Any details what exactly You build and how It will be used?

Answer (score 0):

So in case of vertx you can pass arguments for you class path.

Basically if you need to pass logging configuration, you can do -cp /path/to/logging/properties

Found this after going through a lot of documentation.
Surely will help someone

Answer (score 0):

the file is searched for in the root of the classpath, but this means that you have to pass the directory your logging.properties is in, not the file itself, e.g. in your case

java -cp . -jar xxx.jar

if the file is in the current directory.

not quite sure which path is put in front, maybe you have to remove the logging.properties file from your jar in this case.